# Why does gevent.socket break multiprocessing.connection's auth

Tags: python, connection, multiprocessing, gevent, monkey

I have an application that uses both `grequests` and `multiprocessing.managers` for a combination of IPC communication and Asynchronous RESTful communications over HTTP.

It seems that `grequests`, in using `gevent.monkey`'s `patch_all()` method, breaks the `multiprocessing.connection` module used by the `multiprocessing.manager.SyncManager` class and its derivatives.

This is apparently not an isolated issue, but affects any use case that implements `multiprocessing.connetion`, such as `multiprocessing.pool`, for example.

Drilling down into the code in `gevent/monkey.py`, I found that the swapping of the stdlib `socket` module with `gevent.socket` is what causes the breakage. 
This can be found at line 115 in `gevent/monkey.py` under the `patch_socket()` function:

```
def patch_socket(dns=True, aggressive=True):
    """Replace the standard socket object with gevent's cooperative sockets.
    ...
    _socket.socket = socket.socket # This line breaks multiprocessing.connection!
    ...
```

My question is then why does this swappage break `multiprocessing.connection`, and what advantages are derived from using `gevent.socket` instead of the stdlib's `socket` module? That is, what performance loss, if any, will I incur from not patching the `socket` module?

### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clientWithGeventMonkeyPatch.py", line 49, in <module>
    client = GetClient(host, port, authkey)
  File "clientWithGeventMonkeyPatch.py", line 39, in GetClient
    client.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 500, in connect
    conn = Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 175, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in answer_challenge
    response = connection.recv_bytes(256)        # reject large message
IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

### code to reproduce the error

(on ubuntu server 11.10, python2.7.3, with gevent, greenlet, and grequests installed)

manager.py

```
## manager.py
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers
import datetime


class LocalManager(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__type__ = 'LocalManager'

def GetManager(host, port, authkey):
    def getdatetime():
        return '{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())

    LocalManager.register('getdatetime', callable = getdatetime)
    manager = LocalManager(address = (host, port), authkey = authkey)
    manager.start()

    return manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # define our manager connection parameters
    port = 55555
    host = 'localhost'
    authkey = 'auth1234'

    # start a manager
    man = GetManager(host, port, authkey)

    # wait for user input to shut down
    raw_input('return to shutdown')
    man.shutdown()
```

client.py

```
## client.py -- this one works
import time
import multiprocessing.managers

class RemoteClient(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__type__ = 'RemoteClient'

def GetClient(host, port, authkey):
    RemoteClient.register('getdatetime')
    client = RemoteClient(address = (host, port), authkey = authkey)
    client.connect()
    return client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # define our client connection parameters
    port = 55555
    host = 'localhost'
    authkey = 'auth1234'

    # start a manager
    client = GetClient(host, port, authkey)
    print 'connected', client
    print 'client.getdatetime()', client.getdatetime()
    # wait a couple of seconds, then do it again
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'client.getdatetime()', client.getdatetime()

    # exit...
```

clientWithGeventMonkeyPatch.py

```
## clientWithGeventMonkeyPatch.py -- breaks, depending on patch_all() parameters        
import time
import multiprocessing.managers


# this part is copied from grequests
# bear in mind that it doesn't actually do anything in this module.
try:
    import gevent
    from gevent import monkey as curious_george
    from gevent.pool import Pool
except ImportError:
    raise RuntimeError('Gevent is required for grequests.')

# this line causes breakage of the multiprocessing.manager connection auth method:
# Monkey-patch. 
# patch_all() parameters with default values:  socket=True, dns=True, time=True, select=True, thread=True, os=True, ssl=True, aggressive=True

curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False) # breaks
#~ curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False, socket = False) # works!
#~ curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False, socket = True, aggressive = True, dns = True) # same as (thread=False, select=False); breaks
#~ curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False, socket = True, aggressive = True, dns = False) # breaks
#~ curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False, socket = True, aggressive = False, dns = True) # breaks
#~ curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False, socket = True, aggressive = False, dns = False) # breaks







class RemoteClient(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__type__ = 'RemoteClient'

def GetClient(host, port, authkey):
    RemoteClient.register('getdatetime')
    client = RemoteClient(address = (host, port), authkey = authkey)
    client.connect()
    return client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # define our client connection parameters
    port = 55555
    host = 'localhost'
    authkey = 'auth1234'

    # start a manager
    client = GetClient(host, port, authkey)
    print 'connected', client
    print 'client.getdatetime()', client.getdatetime()
    # wait a couple of seconds, then do it again
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'client.getdatetime()', client.getdatetime()

    # exit...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't patch the socket module, `gevent`'s ability to not block on network operations won't be available, and thus most of the benefit of using `gevent` in the first place won't be available.

`gevent` and `multiprocessing` aren't really designed to play nicely with one another - `gevent` mostly assumes that you're doing your network connections through it, and not bypassing the highest level Python socket interfaces (which `multiprocessing` does).

Comment: I see. Would that then point to `[Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable` being the result of attempting a blocking read on a non-blocking socket connection?

Comment: Though I'm not a gevent developer and haven't looked at its internals recently, that seems like a very likely explanation - the non-blocking socket doesn't have any data to read yet, so it raises a "not yet" exception which `gevent` would normally catch, but the call path is bypassing that portion of `gevent`, so the exception isn't caught.

Comment: that sounds reasonable. I think my best course of action here is to replace `multiprocessing.connection`'s socket creation method with one that is `gevent`-aware, and therefore able to go around it and use the original stdlib `socket` module instead. (Of course, this is the short-term, least-breaking solution, but not the best one, IMO--the best being gevent and elements that use it not overwriting stdlib components and using a proper try...except... on their import to deal with ambiguous imports.)